# Why isn't my animation working in Internet Explorer 10+?

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, animation

Why is this code not working in `IE 10 +`

```css
.logo{float: left;width: 250px;}
.logo img{float: left;}
.logo img.leftLog{width: 83%;}
.logo img.rightLog{width:13%;margin-left: 4%;background-repeat: no-repeat;

animation: 4s linear 0s normal none infinite running spin;
-moz-animation: 4s linear 0s normal none infinite running spin;
-o-animation: 4s linear 0s normal none infinite running spin;
-webkit-animation: 4s linear 0s normal none infinite running spin;
-khtml-animation: 4s linear 0s normal none infinite running spin;
-ms-animation: 4s linear 0s normal none infinite running spin;

transform: rotate(360deg); 
-moz-transform: rotate(360deg); 
-o-transform: rotate(360deg); 
-webkit-transform: rotate(360deg); 
-khtml-transform: rotate(360deg); 
-ms-transform: rotate(360deg); 
}

@keyframes spin {100% {transform: rotate(0deg);}}
@-moz-keyframes spin {100% {-moz-transform: rotate(0deg);}}
@-o-keyframes spin {100% {-o-transform: rotate(0deg);}}
@-webkit-keyframes spin {100% {-webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);}}
@-ms-keyframes spin {100% {-ms-transform: rotate(0deg);}}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <a href="" class="logo">
<img src="http://png-3.vector.me/files/images/1/3/139812/arrow_logo_thumb.jpg" alt="logo" class="leftLog">
<img src="http://iconizer.net/files/IconSweets_2/orig/reload_refresh.png" alt="" class="rightLog">
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: CSS animation isn't implemented in IE8 or IE9. The first version of IE with support for animation was IE10.

Comment: And what about 10 or 11 ? @JamesDonnelly Did you check code in IE 10 or 11. you just downvote without seeing issue.

Comment: CSS3 animation will support in only from ie10+ and above.

Comment: @Maddy IE11 doesn't like your `animation` declaration. I don't know enough about CSS animations to be able to tell you why though: http://i.imgur.com/9eNxZai.png.

Comment: Okay @JamesDonnelly I understand. I am sorry but you have around 60k rep. So please don't down vote any other, if you don't have enough knowledge. :)

Comment: @Maddy 1. wasn't me, 2. downvotes are anonymous on SO anyway, so assumptions are bad, 3. usually I only downvote questions which I also vote to close - this isn't one of those questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with the annotation of the animation object. Within IE there is a different annotation needed as can be seen in this [documentation from MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/hh673530.aspx). The problem is that animation can contain 6 properties and you define 8 which IE does not like.

So instead of defining the animation like this:

```
animation: 4s linear 0s normal none infinite running spin;
```

You have to define it like this:

```
  animation-name: spin;
  animation-duration: 4s;
  animation-timing-function: linear;
  animation-delay: none;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-direction: running;
```

To make it more understandably I wrote out the properties

See demo:

```css
.logo{float: left;width: 250px;}
.logo img{float: left;}
.logo img.leftLog{width: 83%;}
.logo img.rightLog{width:13%;margin-left: 4%;background-repeat: no-repeat;

  animation-name: spin;
  animation-duration: 4s;
  animation-timing-function: linear;
  animation-delay: none;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-direction: running;
  

-moz-animation: 4s linear 0s normal none infinite running spin;
-o-animation: 4s linear 0s normal none infinite running spin;
-webkit-animation: 4s linear 0s normal none infinite running spin;
-khtml-animation: 4s linear 0s normal none infinite running spin;
-ms-animation: 4s linear 0s normal none infinite running spin;

transform: rotate(360deg); 
-moz-transform: rotate(360deg); 
-o-transform: rotate(360deg); 
-webkit-transform: rotate(360deg); 
-khtml-transform: rotate(360deg); 
-ms-transform: rotate(360deg); 
}

@keyframes spin {100% {transform: rotate(0deg);}}
@-moz-keyframes spin {100% {-moz-transform: rotate(0deg);}}
@-o-keyframes spin {100% {-o-transform: rotate(0deg);}}
@-webkit-keyframes spin {100% {-webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);}}
@-ms-keyframes spin {100% {-ms-transform: rotate(0deg);}}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <a href="" class="logo">
<img src="http://png-3.vector.me/files/images/1/3/139812/arrow_logo_thumb.jpg" alt="logo" class="leftLog">
<img src="http://iconizer.net/files/IconSweets_2/orig/reload_refresh.png" alt="" class="rightLog">
  </a>
</div>
```